# removing the remainder of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I would like to remove the remainder from a fraction if possible. I want a function

$$f(x,y)  = x/y - remainder$$

for example

$$f(3,2) = 1$$
$$f(7,2) = 3$$
$$f(12,5) = 2$$

It seems so simple but its been bugging me for a while. Please help.

Comment: What properties do you want this remainder to have? Do you want it to be an integer? Because it seems to me like you're looking at standard integer division.

Comment: Do you mean something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions?

Comment: x and y are both integers. The output of f(x,y) is also an integer. Yes I need something like a floor function but I want it from first principles if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [division with remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_with_remainder)  We have $y=\lfloor \frac yx \rfloor x+r$, where $f(x,y)=\lfloor \frac yx \rfloor, r=y-\lfloor \frac yx \rfloor x$.  What do you mean by "from first principles?"

Comment: I want to define floor from first principles if possible. So knowing what x and y are, using basic arithmetic determine what the remainder is.

Answer (score 1):

Floor function will do what you want . Floor function of the value obtained by normal divison .